# When the zabbix proxy is restarted, the log [/var/log/messages] monitoring item reports the old log alarm information

Tags: zabbix

When the zabbix proxy is restarted, the log[/var/log/messages] monitoring item reports the old log alarm information
zabbix server version:5.0.5

Answer (score 0):

Usually you will have to use the `skip` mode, because the first time agent will check the log file, it will check from the beginning.

See https://blog.zabbix.com/zabbix-log-file-monitoring/7378/